# Ruby 3.0 / Rails 6 connection to SQL Server via ODBC?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, odbc

What is the best way to connect to MS SQL Server from Rails 6? I'm trying to port a rails app that has been developed with a SQLite backend onto Azure, where the preference is to use the Azure SQL database.

For testing I have an MS SQL Server Docker image running locally. After a bit of fiddling, I have the ActiveRecord sqlserver_adapter correctly loading - but I'm having problems with the ruby rails-odbc driver. It's specified in my Gemfile:

```
gem 'tiny_tds'
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter'
gem 'rails-odbc'
```

But when I run `bundle install` I get the following error:

```
steve@AMEYLT722355L:~/git/risk_front$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Could not find gem 'rails-odbc x86_64-linux' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
```

Anyone know how to find this version of the rails-odbc driver, or alternately another way of connecting to MS SQL Server from Rails 6.

Thanks

Steve

Comment: Why do you want to use an ODBC connection?

Comment: @engineersmnky. I'm looking for any possible way of connecting to MS SQL Server from Rails 6. If you can suggest an alternative to ODBC, I'd be delighted ... :-)

Comment: Sure just `tiny_tds` and `activerecord-sqlserver-adapter` work fine. We have used this combination for at least 10 projects spanning rails 3.2 (1.9.3) -> rails 6.1 (2.7.2) so I can definitely tell you it works

Comment: Thxs @engineersmnky - problem was that the Gemfile was for some reason loading activerecord-sqlserver-adapter 2.3.8 not 6.0.0. All sorted!